# missing footer on category pages - Magento 1.9

Tags: category, cms, footer

I cannot workout why but i seem to be missing the footer section on my store when viewing category pages.

http://dev.colourcalendars.com/a4-wall-calendars.html

In all other sections this seems to display perfectly but for some reason is missing on the category sections - is there something i am missing with this?

Any help would be appreciated because i cannot work this out??

Comment: If you check the source of this page you can see that the HTML has not been entirely rendered. It stops here: `<div class="aggregate-rating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"><span itemprop="name">`. Check your logs and post of you generate this aggregate-rating block.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of the page you'll notice the markup ends after a `<span itemprop="name">` which means somewhere along the way there's a fatal error. By the looks of it, I'd say it's a plugin or a theme typo.

Try enabling developer mode and/or logging, and then check for errors in `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log`. If it's a fatal error though, this would be reported in the web server error log file

Comment: ah yes, i see the code around tha area - removing this code loads the footer section back up on these pages:

Comment: <!--<div class="aggregate-rating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <span itemprop="name"><?php echo $_product->getName()?></span>
      <?php $array = $this->helper('yotpo/richSnippets')->getRichSnippet($this); ?>
      <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue"><?php echo $array["average_score"]; ?></span>/5
        based on <span itemprop="reviewCount"><?php echo $array["reviews_count"]; ?></span> customer reviews
      </span>
</div> -->

Comment: btw, the way you commented the code here won't prevent the php code from running. you need to use php comments to take out that part.

Comment: i have removed this section completely from the page - i aded the comments first and realised that would not work so removed the lot - can anyone see an issue iwth the code and why it breaks the page?